# Haskell, How could I construct a new datatype so that the value of that type is 1 or 2 or 3?

Tags: haskell

I want to construct a new data type called Oct, and it should return 1 or 2 or 3, so my code is something like this :
data Oct = 1|2|3

but the Haskell shows the error like this: Cannot parse data constructor in a data/newtype declaration: 1

And I don`t know what does this error means. how should I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to limit the value of `Int` to one of `{1,2,3}`. If so, you can define a *newtype* `Oct` as:

```
newtype Oct = Oct Int deriving(Show)
```

and then define a function `oct` that makes `Oct` as:

```
oct :: Int -> Oct
oct n 
   | n > 0 && n < 4 = Oct n 
   | otherwise      = error "invalid value: " ++ show n
```

If throwing `error` is not acceptable, then maybe `Maybe` will help:

```
oct :: Int -> Maybe Oct
oct n 
   | n > 0 && n < 4 = Just (Oct n) 
   | otherwise      = Nothing
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7):

You can't really make arbitrary subtypes like that.  What you can do is make a data type with three constructors, you just have to understand some things about data declarations:

When you declare a new data type, you declare it *with* its constructors.  The constructors you use are *brand new* names that don't already have a meaning.  The datatype and its constructors must all begin with a capital letter. So you say

```
data Oct = One | Two | Three
```

This declares the *type* `Oct` and three *values* `One`, `Two`, and `Three` -- four declarations at once.

Another alternative is to use a [smart constructor](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors) with a type like

```
newtype Oct = Oct Int
```

as shown in more detail in @Nawaz's answer.

There is a way to make numeric literals work, so you can use `1 :: Oct`, but for this case it's not good because (the way the libraries are designed) numeric literals ought to come with numeric structure as well, which `Oct` doesn't have (well, unless you want to start doing fancy math).  Also using `4 :: Oct` would typecheck but would be a runtime error, which we also don't like.

Answer (score 1):

> but the Haskell shows the error like this: Cannot parse data constructor in a data/newtype declaration: 1

This error message tells you that `1` is not a valid name for a data constructor. The rules for names of data constructors are similar to those of variables in most languages. Here the compiler complains because the name starts with a digit, which is not allowed.

Comment: "data type" is the wrong phrase to use for describing a data constructor.

Comment: @amalloy Thank you for the feedback. I have made the suggested change.